What old video game reverse engineering communities or forums are still up?
Can anyone tell me what old video game reverse engineering communities or forums are still up? Years ago I posted about older game file formats but no one replied on XeNTaX.

your question is not specifically about a reverse engineering problem ... also the tags do not match the question
